# In Stein and Shakarchi Complex Analysis, Exercise 8 in Chapter 4.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I have question about fourier inversion formula.

If we use the fourier inversion formula, f and $\hat f$ satisfy the decay condition or moderate decreasing.

In Exercise 8, Ch4,

> Suppose $\hat f$ has compact support contained in [-M,M] and let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$. Show that $a_n=\frac{(2 \pi i)^n}{n!}\int_{-M}^{M}\hat f(\xi)\xi^nd\xi$.

I thought this problem can be solved by using the fourier inversion formula. However, I don't know why it can be applied the fourier inversion formula. 
Any help is appreciated.. !!!

Answer (score 1):

$$f\left( x \right)=\sum\limits_{{}}^{{}}{{{a}_{n}}{{z}^{n}}}=\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{{e}^{2\pi ikx}}\hat{f}\left( k \right)dk}$$
Hence
$$\oint{\frac{1}{{{z}^{m+1}}}\sum\limits_{{}}^{{}}{{{a}_{n}}{{z}^{n}}}dz}=\oint{\frac{1}{{{z}^{m+1}}}dz}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{{e}^{2\pi ikz}}\hat{f}\left( k \right)dk}$$
Where the contour is a circle surrounding z=0.  Hence
$$2\pi i{{a}_{m}}=\oint{\frac{{{e}^{2\pi ikz}}}{{{z}^{m+1}}}dz}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\hat{f}\left( k \right)dk}$$
Using the taylor series for the exponential we have $\oint{\frac{{{e}^{2\pi ikz}}}{{{z}^{m+1}}}dz}=2\pi i\frac{{{\left( 2\pi i \right)}^{m}}}{m!}$ , hence
$${{a}_{m}}=\frac{{{\left( 2\pi i \right)}^{m}}}{m!}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\hat{f}\left( k \right){{k}^{m}}dk}$$

Comment: Why $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat f(\xi)e^{2 \pi \xi  x}d\xi$ ?? We don't know $f$ and $\hat f$ satisfy decay condition or  moderate decreasing.

Comment: it has compact support, so it is zero outside [-M,M], which just changes the terminals to -M,M.